# angularjs regex filter syntax highlighter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter, syntax-highlighting

please take a look at this plunker:  http://plnkr.co/edit/OIFu07GS0ZJQOdmpDnXB?p=preview

i am trying to create a syntax highlighter with angular.  I have the filter working 80%.  The regex is correct but the .replace() it "writes" the html as text on the pre and not rendering it as html.

take a look and you will understand what I am trying to do.

I know there are codemirror and ace directives but they are just too big for what I need.

anyone know how to fix it?

the correct output should be something like this:

```
<pre>
    <span class="string">1</span>
    <span class="string">2</span>
    <span class="string">3</span> 
    #This is a mysql syntax highlighter
    -- This is a comment/*
    And this is a multi line comment
    SELECT things FROM table;*/
</pre>
```

currently everything between pre is rendered as text.

any ideas?
thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do this with a filter, try a directive.

Below is an example, fairly straightforward. I first changed the filter to a service (though you can use the filter similarly with `$filter` if you want but I don't see why). Then I use `$interpolate` to create an interpolation function, described [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24interpolate):

> Compiles a string with markup into an interpolation function. This service is used by the HTML $compile service for data binding. See $interpolateProvider for configuring the interpolation markup.

You can see in the example that the strings `'1'`, `'2'` and `'3'` are highlighted because I added `style="color:red"`, and they have the class as well.

**Edit**: edited solution with usage of [ngModelController](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController) to make changes to the textarea appear in the element below with angular's data binding. Note the change to the snippet element: `<snippet ng-model="txt">`

---

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['syntax']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.txt = "1 2 3 \n #This is a mysql syntax highlighter\n-- This is a comment/*\nAnd this is a multi line comment\nSELECT things FROM table;*/\nSELECT \nag.name AS agent, `d.date`, d.first_payment_date, d.account_number, ";
});


angular.module('syntax', [])
  .service('formatter', function () {
    return function (input) {
      if (input) {
        return input.replace(/(\d+)/g, "<span class=\"string\" style=\"color:red\">$1</span>");
      }
    }
})

.directive('snippet', function($timeout, $interpolate, formatter) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template:'<pre><code></code></pre>',
        replace:true,
        require: '?ngModel',
        link:function(scope, elm, attrs, ngModel){ 
          ngModel.$render = function(){
            var tmp =  $interpolate(scope.txt)(scope);
            elm.find('code').html(formatter(tmp)); 
          }
        }
    };
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/783ML4Y2qH8oMLarf0kg?p=preview

Comment: thank you very much. that worked.  is there any way to make it editable, so whatever I type either in the textarea or the snippet, the snippet uses the classes to highlight the text?  I tried the ng-model but it didn't work. thanx again

Comment: Edited with a solution that implements this.

Comment: i am trying to use this inside a ng-repeat but it doesn't work.  anyone know how it can work with an ng-repeat?  here is an updated plunker with the ng-repeat.   http://plnkr.co/edit/PRndhLnsx29abPhIIB8c?p=preview

Comment: Here is an AngularJS directive that does this: http://ngmodules.org/modules/angular-highlightjs it uses: http://highlightjs.org/static/test.html